# Connecting to Azure SQL with AD Password Authentication from ASP.NET app fails with "Need user interface to continue"

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I can connect to an Azure SQL database using AD Password Authentication both in SSMS and with the following code dropped into a new console application:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=my-server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=myuser@mydomain.com;Password=mypassword;Connect Timeout=30;Authentication=\"Active Directory Password\""))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT SUSER_SNAME()", connection))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have successfully logged on as: " + (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, using this exact same code in a new ASP.NET MVC or API or Mobile Apps web application yields the following `AdalException` on `connection.Open()`:

> Need user interface to continue

...which is then wrapped in a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` with this message:

> Failed to authenticate the user myuser@mydomain.com in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).
>   Error code 0xCAA10001; state 10
>   Need user interface to continue.

I've tried using that connection code in the Application_Start, the Startup.cs, and in a controller method with no luck.

Any ideas? I changed my target framework for the project to `.NET Framework 4.6.1` in the project properties because the [SQL Database AAD Authentication article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/) specifies the requirements as greater than 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the code samples in GitHub demo
see https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/security/azure-active-directory-auth

They show 3 examples how to authenticate with Azure AD auth into SQL DB using 
1.  User/password 
2.  Integrated authentication
3.  JSON Web Token (JWT) with certificate

Thanks,
Mirek

Comment: I did, that's where I got the code snippet I've included above. The code sample works in a separate console application. My question is around why its not working in a ASP.NET application.

Comment: Could you please open an Azure customer case for this item? Also in parallel please contact  MFAforSQLDBDWPreview@microsoft.com alias and describe the problem. Thanks, Mirek

Comment: @Mirek : I have added new post related to the same bug, can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973431/error-in-ad-integration-with-azure-sql-paas-c-sharp-and-net

Answer (score 0):

Could you please open an Azure customer case for this item?
Also in parallel please contact  MFAforSQLDBDWPreview@microsoft.com alias and describe the problem.
Thanks,
Mirek